# rviz tutorial markers

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I think some information is missing on the Tutorial for Marker visualization in rviz (Here would be the link to rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes if I had enough karma).

I should be written somewhere that "fixed frame" should be set to "/my_frame" in rviz otherwise nothing can be seen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146916/rviz-tutorial-markers/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-04-03**:
I had the same issue and tried to set it to /my_frame but that didn't exist either.  I got stuck and asked for help and the community was not very helpful and I've never run rviz since.  I will probably figure it out someday but am quite frustrated with the tutorial at the moment.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-04-03**:
Tutorials marked as "beginner" level should be newbie friendly (in my opinion) and work right out of the box with no external knowledge required of the tool that is being demonstrated by said tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well it says that you should read the user guide if not familiar with rviz, and there it explains about the fixed_frame. That being said, it would not hurt to put this hint directly in the tutorial. It is a wiki, so feel free to edit it accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0